# SQL Server 2012 getting column can't be null error when the column has a default constraint.

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, constraints

Consider the following schema...

```
create table dbo.dg_world_records(
                                     WorldRecordId    int          not null identity(1,1)
                                   , GameTypeId       int          not null
                                   ,  PlayerId        int          not null
                                   , NumberOfValues   int          not null
                                   , TotalTime        int          not null
                                   , DateOfRecord     datetime     not null
                                   , GameId           int          not null
                                   , UTCInserted      datetime     not null
                                   , UTCUpdated       datetime     not null
                                   , SrvName          varchar(30)  not null
                                 )


go
alter table dg_world_records add constraint dg_world_records_worldrecordid_pk primary key (worldrecordid)
go
alter table dg_world_records add constraint dg_world_records_utcinserted_df default getutcdate() for utcinserted
go
alter table dg_world_records add constraint dg_world_records_utcupdated_df default getutcdate() for utcupdated
go
alter table dg_world_records add constraint dg_world_records_srvname_df default @@servername for srvname
go
```

I'm defining not null columns and for the last three columns (UTCInserted, UTCUpdated, & SrvName) I'm creating default constraints.

I've done this many times on my company's development server and Everything works good.

However, on my local instance of SQL Server 2012 the following insert statement is throwing an error.

```
insert into dbo.dg_world_records(gametypeid, playerid, numberofvalues, totaltime, dateofrecord, gameid)
values(11, 1, 365, 430000, getdate(), -1)
```

Here is the error message...

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SrvName', table 'dateguess.dbo.dg_world_records'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

My guess is that there is an environment settings in SQL Server that allows you to not specify a value for a not null column where a default constraint is defined.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you 100% certain you have a constraint on the SrvName column? That code should work just fine.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table?

Comment: I just ran the code our SQL 2016 dev server and it worked. No trigger as the the table was dropped before running my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem is the following statement...

```
@@servername
```

This statement was returning null.

To fix this I had add the local server via sp_addserver...

```
sp_addserver 'LT9LHJKV1\SQLSERVERROCKS', local
```

Then I had to restart SQL Server.

After that @@servername returns a value and my insert statement works.